# SetInputType in Samsung tab 4 not working

Tags: tabs, android-edittext

I have an application in which the editText field's input type is set to numeric programmatically like below

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

This is working in samsung galaxy tab 3 and the android version is 4.2.2

But on samsung tab 4 it is not working. android version is 4.4.2

Can anyone help me?

Screenshot of tab 3

[image: Screenshot of tab 3]

Screenshot of tab 4

[image: Screenshot of tab 4]

Sometimes it doesn't show up the keypad, just shows a grey block.
Thanks in advance..